# unable to start tomcat server

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04

Tomcat worked fine and suddenly after disabling the ufw I am getting the following message when trying to get the status of tomcat. 
BTW I am running Ubuntu & tomcat8

```
root@saba:~# sudo systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-19 03:12:59 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 18268 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 18253 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18265 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 19 03:12:59 saba systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 19 03:12:59 saba systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 19 03:12:59 saba systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Following is the output for the command bash -x /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

- os400=false
- case "`uname`" in
  ++ uname
- PRG=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
- '[' -h /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh ']'
  ++ dirname /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
- PRGDIR=/opt/tomcat/bin
- EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh
- false
- '[' '!' -x /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh ']'
- exec /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
  Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
  Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
  Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
  Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
  Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
  /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found

Comment: Run the script `/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` with `bash -x /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` and add the output to your question...

Comment: @heemayl output added

Comment: I had same issue then I used this command `bash -x /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh` and found out I have an extra "-" when I put my own comment in. <!-- comment -->